# Python Beginner Question: how does this code work?

Tags: python

How does the statement inside word_list work?

```
used_letters = ["a", "b", "d"]
word = ["a", "b", "d"]
word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else '-' for letter in word]
print(word_list)
```

Comment: It's called [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension).

Comment: Does this help? https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: There's also a [conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/4518341) in there. (@khelwood, you could add this to the duplicates list.)